# One storeview error to many redirect

Tags: error, magento2.3, template, store-view

We have a `multistore` in `multilanguage` and as test we set one to connect the media and static url through static.domain.com to a CDN but that is not working.

But now the template for that `storeview` and the admin are messed up. I looked in `core_config_data` but I can not the change the static url for one store in there.

We tried the normal things, reindex, deploy static content, set to production etc etc but that is not working.

Is there an other place where I can change it back to blank?

This is the domain: https://bakmina.com/

Comment: Did you try clearing cache? Delete var/cache folder?

Comment: Yep delete it all. There must be a file for each storeview i think where the configuration is stored. But no idea where that files is

Answer (score 0):

To correct this, please try to set Use Secure URLs in Admin to true, in System -> Config -> General -> Web.

or connect to database and change following record value to 1 :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%web/secure/use_in_adminhtml%';
```

Note: if you have multiple stores make sure it's on all store.

Comment: Thats the problem. Admin is messed up to. And in the core_config_data it is not per storeview

Comment: ok you can make changes globally

Comment: Yes, but that is not working, you should think there must be somewhere in the database a file / record where it is stored. But I can not find it.